# how to sanitize sql parameters pass to st_centroid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, sanitization

I am trying to sanitize the parameters pass to ST_Centroid but I am getting a syntax error.

[st_centroid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html)

```
"SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 ))) as centroid"
    
sql = ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql_array(['SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(MULTIPOINT ( ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ? ))) as centroid', min_longitude, min_latitude, min_longitude, max_latitude, max_longitude, min_latitude, max_longitude, max_latitude])

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)&.to_a&.first["centroid"] || ""
```

Syntax Error

```
from /home/aniket/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@project/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec'
Caused by PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 1: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0..
```

It is working fine If I am not sanitizing it

```
sql = "SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( #{min_longitude} #{min_latitude}, #{min_longitude} #{max_latitude}, #{max_longitude} #{min_latitude}, #{max_longitude} #{max_latitude} )')) as centroid";

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)&.to_a&.first["centroid"]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0 )')) as centroid
=> "POINT(0 0)"
```

Comment: the query should be `sanitize_sql_array(["SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT(...)'))",..])`, right ? note about `"` and `'`

Comment: Lam Phan  I didn't get you. Could you ellaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to document `MULTIPOINT` should be quote by `'`, and i see that you miss that when `sanitize_sql_array`, so try this

```rb
sql = ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql_array([
 "SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('MULTIPOINT ( ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ? )')) as centroid", 
 min_longitude, min_latitude, min_longitude, 
 max_latitude, max_longitude, min_latitude, 
 max_longitude, max_latitude
])
```